# Marshmallow 3.10.0: ensure_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'

Tags: python, unit-testing, marshmallow

I am trying to migrate one project that I work on from Marshmallow version 3.0.0b14 to 3.10.0. However when I run the tests I get the following error many times:

```
self = <PasswordResetQueryParameters(many=False)>, tag = 'pre_load'
pass_many = False, data = {'email': 'foobar@example.com'}, many = False
original_data = {'email': 'foobar@example.com'}, kwargs = {'partial': False}
key = ('pre_load', False), attr_name = 'ensure_dict', processor_kwargs = {}

    def _invoke_processors(
        self,
        tag: str,
        *,
        pass_many: bool,
        data,
        many: bool,
        original_data=None,
        **kwargs
    ):
        key = (tag, pass_many)
        for attr_name in self._hooks[key]:
            # This will be a bound method.
            processor = getattr(self, attr_name)
    
            processor_kwargs = processor.__marshmallow_hook__[key]
            pass_original = processor_kwargs.get("pass_original", False)
    
            if many and not pass_many:
                if pass_original:
                    data = [
                        processor(item, original, many=many, **kwargs)
                        for item, original in zip(data, original_data)
                    ]
                else:
                    data = [processor(item, many=many, **kwargs) for item in data]
            else:
                if pass_original:
                    data = processor(data, original_data, many=many, **kwargs)
                else:
>                   data = processor(data, many=many, **kwargs)
E                   TypeError: ensure_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'

.tox/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py:1227: TypeError
```

Although I did add `**kwargs` to the decorated function ensure_dict like recommended in this link:

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/upgrading.html#decorated-methods-and-handle-error-receive-many-and-partial

I changed the decorated function like this:

```
@pre_load
def ensure_dict(self, data, **kwargs):
```

But this did not work either. Any idea how to fix this? thanks.

Comment: This should be the right fix. We can't do much more to help without seeing the code.

Comment: @Jérôme , I have fixed it, thanks. Now, I have another question: the 'unknown' property is not respected and I tried to overwrite it at instansiation (https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/upgrading.html#schemas-raise-validationerror-when-deserializing-data-with-unknown-keys) but it gives me this error: ```__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given``` . Any idea?

Comment: Please open another question with details.

Comment: @Jérôme , yes you are right :) done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625372/marshmallow-3-10-0-init-takes-one-positional-argument-but-4-were-given